# How can I select the sum of a column from a table with multiple entries per metric?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I have a table in MySQL which records periodic metrics for certain data points. This table effectively has a record for every set interval for each metric (defined here by metric_id). I want to know how to select the sum of a group of metrics having the latest timestamp for each one.

```
mysql> SELECT value, timestamp, metric_id FROM datapoint
WHERE metric_id IN (11, 13) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2;
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| value | timestamp           | metric_id |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| 28    | 2016-07-26 21:37:04 |        13 |
|  4    | 2016-07-26 21:37:05 |        11 |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I want is to select the sum (32) from the above table given the metric_id's in the IN statement where for each record, it's the latest one by timestamp.

Comment: Add a clear sample result here.. even image

Comment: What can I add an image of? I just want one field SUM(value).

Comment: do you want to sum all value fields according to its timestamp?is that ryt?

Comment: I want to show the value of 32. This value is the sum of the latest datapoints for both metrics in the IN statement.

Comment: sum statement need a specific group by, from other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery in the query below identifies the latest record by timestamp for each `metric_id` group.  This is then used to select the values for each of those most recent records, and the values are then summed in the outer query.

```
SELECT SUM(t1.value)
FROM datapoint t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT metric_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM datapoint
    GROUP BY metric_id
) t2
    ON t1.metric_id = t2.metric_id AND
       t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
WHERE t1.metric_id IN (11, 13)
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you Tim. I have yet to master inner joins.

Comment: It did, I have to wait 5 more minutes though :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT sum(value), date(timestamp), metric_id FROM datapoint
WHERE metric_id IN (11, 13) group by date(timestamp)  ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Reds, this, like before, sums up all the values not just the latest one. I get some huge number.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(value) from datapoint
where metric_id in (select metric_id from datapoint group by metric_id having max(timestamp));
```